# Trouble with downloading bioconductor package

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I'm trying to download the package "BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19" but it's not working.
Here's the code :

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19")
```

but everytime I try, I get this :

The downloaded source packages are in

```
C:\Users\halak\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWm6xIJ\downloaded_packages

Old packages: 'exactRankTests', 'haven', 'RcppParallel', 'rtracklayer'
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]:
```

I typed a and it still didn't work.

I also updated the packages and this still happens.

Comment: That's not necessarily an error - just a notification that some of your packages aren't up to the latest version. If the installation is actually failing, we'll need the information from the error instead. You can check whether it worked by trying library(BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19). If it tells you "object not found" then the install actually failed and you should try it again to see where the actual install error is.

Comment: I don't see any error messages. What makes you think "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Warning message:
In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: That's the error I recieve everytime I try to download it